# How to show my profile page using devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have a devise model with the default fields email and password, and a few more that I manually added like full name, age, etc... I'd like to have a page that shows the profile details but I'm not seeing how can I do this.

Somewhere in my application.html view i do this :

<%= link_to "Profile", current_account%>

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controller

```
class YoursController < ApplicationController
 def profile
   @account = current_account
 end
end
```

Route

```
get "myprofile" => "yours#profile", :as => :myprofile
```

View `/yours/profile.html.erb`

```
<%= @account.email %>
<%= @account.etc %>
```

Link to current profile

```
<%= link_to "My Profile", myprofile_path %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Devise doesn't provide any show action on registration controller by default. You need to override devise custom routing for this.

```
devise_scope :user do
  get '/users/:id' => 'devise/registrations#show'
end

after

devise_for :users
```

Now You can add show action in your devise registration controller.
If you don't want to override devise custom controller then you can create your own users controller and changes routes like this:

```
devise_scope :user do
  get '/users/:id' => 'users#show'
end
```

Comment: I got this error undefined method `account_path' for #<#<Class:0xb4a42644>:0xb4a42090> at this line : <li> <%= link_to "Profile", current_account %> </li>

Comment: my devise model is accounts instead of users

Comment: change `users` to `accounts` and `:user` to `account` If this still not work create accounts controller and make routes like this `resources :accounts` this will definitely works. You have so many ways to do that.